# Can "Javascript" Decrypt the Data, Encrypted by PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, json, encryption

When I *normally* return the Ajax/JSON from PHP, the Javascript get it and stores it inside a variable, like: `var myJSON = ajaxReturnedJSON;` Then Javascript read it.

I'm seriously curious to know if, php encrypts the json:

```
echo json_encode($encrypted_data); //using some key like: "abc123"
```

- Then, can `Javascript` decrypt it back by using same key?
- Is there any common `encrypt/decrypt` method between php and js?

***Note***: I understand `key` will be visible at JS side but i can also use JS Obfucators to `hex` the whole characters, whole JS `file`. So more or less it will protect, rather then plain/nothing.

*Welcome to any ideas and discussions.*

Comment: Whatever you think you're doing, you aren't. If you're unencrypting something with javascript, you're using a key/encryption method visible for and useable by everyone, hence you might as well not.

Comment: What's the point in keeping your decrypt code & key in js, when you know that it is readable by the user?

Comment: So how were the contents of $encrypted_JSON encrypted before?

Comment: Do you mean Encode and Decode?
This is not the same as Encrypt and Decrypt.
You propably mean encode (as json in this case)

Comment: What about using HTTPS? Wouldn't that cover your use-case?

Comment: Decrypting with JavaScript and key being stored in it is like telling someone hey my door is locked for you but oh here is the key to it

Comment: Hey, i updated the question. I understand `key` will be visible at JS side but i can also use JS Obfucators to `hex` the whole characters, whole JS `file`. So more or less it will protect, rather then plain/nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Encryption and decryption algorithms are just mathematical operations which can be performed in virtually any programming language. Javascript being a programming language you can implement any decryption algorithm in it you need.

This is typically pretty pointless though if this Javascript is running in the browser. Encryption is used to hide information from somebody. In a server-client scenario, there are three parties: web server, browser/user, third parties. Now:

- You don't need to hide information from the web server, because that's you.
- You cannot hide information from the browser/user, since what's the point? Just don't output the information in the first place if you need to hide it. If the browser/Javascript can decrypt the information, so can the user, so it's not hidden.
- Transport encryption may hide the information from the prying eyes of third parties (men in the middle and such), but for that there's already a better solution: SSL/TLS. Also, if you're sending all the information needed to decrypt data down to the client, third parties can intercept this as well and decrypt the data just like the client.

Comment: I understand `key` will be visible at JS side but i can also use JS Obfucators to `hex` the whole characters, whole JS `file`. So more or less it will protect, rather then plain and nothing.

Comment: It's just *obfuscation* in any way. If I, the user, want the information, I'll just set a breakpoint on the script which decrypts the information and read the decrypted content right out of memory. Whatever happens in the browser is/can be completely transparent to anybody who knows where to look. It's not secure. What are you trying to hide and why?

Comment: Customer Location Coordinates for Google Map. Just need to output on map, but can NOT let it be leaked out.

Comment: If you're displaying them on a map... aren't they "leaked"?!

Comment: Displaying as pin points are ok, as long as it is huge count, and the exact lat/lng are not given as a one complete data bundle.

Comment: Any way you turn it, you need to have a "data bundle" in your public code somewhere. You can try to obfuscate it with some simple base64 encoding/decoding or a standard Javascript compressor, but it will never be actually hidden.